# Include widget within newsletter template?

Tags: widgets, newsletter

I'm using the Newsletter plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/newsletter/) to compose e-mail newsletters. Using the "auto-compose" feature to pull website data via the theme included with the plugin, which I have begun to customise.

It's pulling posts just fine, which is a good start - but I would also like to pull some data that a custom widget on our site is displaying. I'm fairly new to Wordpress and the custom widget in question was not developed by me. Can I include a specific widget via my theme template?

Thanks

Comment: I've tried using this code, but it's not pulling anything.

`<?php the_widget($widget_name); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may already know this, but you need to specify the widget's class name as the $widget_name variable in the  template tag.  For example,

Depending on the widget, you may also need to add parameters to the_widget() to get it to display properly — see notes on thewidget() $instance and $args in the codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget

Alternatively, you can use a plugin like Widgets on Pages, which will let you include a widget anywhere using by using a shortcode like this: [widgets_on_pages id=WidgetName]
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widgets-on-pages/